# How can I know who is at war with whom?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there a way to know which country is at war with another country? I know that there is the Diplomacy Panel, but it only tells **my** situation with other AI civilizations. What I want to know is : Is there a war between other civilizations (AI)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get a lot of information about other civilizations through the `Diplomacy Overview` screen. You can access this screen through the drop down menu in the top right corner. This menu is accessible by using the button next to the `Social Policies` button. Once you open up the Diplomacy Overview, click the tab labelled `Global Politics`. A screen like this should appear, which informs you of the relationships of each opponent:

[image: diplomacy overview screen-global politics tab]

Answer (score 4):

From the Diplomacy Overview click on the tab at the top: **Global Politics**

From here you can see each civilization's :

- Social Policy counts
- Wonders
- war/friendly status for all other civilizations/city states.

Answer (score 0):

The InfoAddict mod is very helpful. One of its screens shows a circle of civilizations with lines connecting them, each colored to denote different conditions: war, open borders, trade agreements, attitude, etc. This is similar to the Diplomacy Advisor from Civ4 but with much more information.

It doesn't break saved game compatibility so you can safely load it for use with an existing game.

Comment: Maybe this was true in April, but as of today (end of July 2012) it says it only works if it is enabled throughout the whole game, and turning it on mid-game I don't see any obvious changes. It's really shameful that Civ 5 downgraded diplomacy so much that a mod is needed to get key functionality back.